# Number of prefixes that match suffixes

Tags: combinatorics

Consider all pairs of strings $A$ and $B$ each of length $n$ where $A_i, B_i \in \{0,1\}$.   We compare all the prefixes of $A$ with all the suffixes of $B$ of the same length and report where they match exactly. For example,  consider $A=01011$ and $B=11010$.  We have $0 = 0$, $01 \ne 10$, $010 = 010$, $0101 \ne 1010$ and $01011 \ne 11010$.

For strings $A$ and $B$ we will report this sequence of matches and non-matches as a tuple of $1$s and $0$s where $1$ indicates a match and $0$ indicates a non-match. So in the above case we get $(1,0,1,0,0)$.

> Taken  over all $2^{2n}$ different pairs of $A$ and $B$ strings, what
>   is the total number of different tuples of matches and
>   non-match one gets?

For $n = 1,\dots, 10$ the exact numbers are $2,4,7,11,17,25,35,48,65,86$.

Comment: This sequence doesn't appear to show up in the online integer sequences database (so be sure to check your numbers), that makes it potentially interesting.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes I also checked the OEIS.  The numbers come  from (simple ) computer code I wrote so are hopefully correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $1,2,4,7,11,17,...$ seems to be

$$\sum_{i=0}^n\kappa(i)$$where $\kappa(i)$ is the *kappa (auto)correlation function*.

No formula for $\kappa(i)$ is known. It appears in OEIS as [A005434](https://oeis.org/A005434) and was introduced in [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316581900388):

- L. J. Guibas and A. M. Odlyzko, Periods in Strings, *Journal of Combinatorial Theory A* 30:1 (1980) 19-42

Comment: That's interesting and also surprising.  That paper seems  to be about periods of a string but here we are comparing two different strings.

Comment: How did you realise the connection?

Comment: You can follow the link to download the article. Instead of comparing prefixes and suffixes, they compare shifted strings (so, in your example, $A$ against a shifted, reversed $B$—which is actually equal to $A$). An autocorrelation starts with $1$, and a correlation starting with $0$ can be thought of as a string of zeros followed by an autocorrelation.